# Flutter Periodically Notifications with Specified Time

Tags: node.js, flutter, notifications

I want to know how can I set periodically notifications in Flutter **with specified time.**

Below code works and I can get notifications but this is work with instant time when the function is triggered.

```
      {required id, required title, required body, required payload}) async {
    
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel-2',
      'channel-2-name',
      channelDescription: 'your channel description-2',
      icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      ticker: 'ticker',
    );
    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      RepeatInterval.daily,
      notificationDetails,
    );
  }
```

I don't want to use time tracker because when application is opened it could be closed any time

Two different solution suggestions come to my mind so far.

1- Use some loop and use 'zonedSchedule' method
2- Use NodeJS with cron and do all of these notifications job in back-end

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer.periodic and call your function inside it.

Your code will look like this.

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: timerTime), (timer) async {
//call your function here
    });
```

Put time in seconds in place of "timertime".

Additionally, if you want to call it when application is in background or foreground then try using flutter background services.